# Virtualbox 5.1.6 issue on MacOS Mojave

Tags: virtualbox, macos-mojave

[image]

Anybody encountered this issue after updating to Mac OS Mojave?

Answer (score -1):

I have also encountered this issue. Noticed it while Mojave was in Beta and I switched back to high sierra. I should've known better. My only solution then was to downgrade. Unfortunately I didn't create a backup before upgrading this time..

Here is a thread on the topic. Currently downloading and reinstalling virtualbox to see if that will help me.

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17805

Edit: Upgrading to the latest version of Virtual Box worked for me.

Comment: how did it go? what version are you installing?

Comment: Worked great. Installed version 5.2.18.